# Save file in Android with spaces in file name

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I need for my android application to save an xml file into the external cache with a file name which contains space.

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(activity
                    .getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Local storage.xml"));

transformer.transform(source, result);
```

When I browse manually into my file directory I find this file : "Local%20storage.xml".

So after when I try to read it with

```
File localStorageXmlFile = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Local storage.xml");
```

But I have a FileNotFoundException because the file "Local storage.xml" can't be found on my device.

Any ideas to solve this?
Seb

Comment: you should not build filenames yourself, use `new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir(), "Local storage.xml")` - it will do that for you. No idea what causes your problem though

Comment: Thanks for this answer but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was hard to identify the source of this problem but it comes from StreamResult which replaces spaces in file name by %20. There is a bug report for this issue [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194359).

And here is the solution :

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(activity
                .getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/" + "Local storage" + ".xml"));
    Result fileResult = new StreamResult(fos);
    transformer.transform(source, fileResult);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks again to both of you for trying to solve my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You saved my day there. I fixed the problem the same way you did.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me and is just one extra line of code

```
String fileName = "name with spaces" + ".xml";                  
fileName.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

Comment: Forward slashes or back slashes?

Comment: Sorry about that back slashes I'll correct it. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using basic URL encoding :

```
File localStorageXmlFile = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Local%20storage.xml");
```

This mgiht help you : [URL encoding table](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Also, when working with file, make sure you're using the right file separator for the OS (in your case the hard coded / should work since Android is linux based but just to make sure.
This could be an other option :

```
File localStorageXmlFile = new File(activity.getExternalCacheDir()
                .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator 
                + "Local storage.xml");
```

Last resort optin would be to try to espace the space. Try replacing " " with "\ ".

Comment: I try your solution Erwald before I post this question and I don't have the exception, but it didn't do what i'm expecting. Indeed, it creates an xml file named "Local%20storage.xml" and not "Local storage.xml".

Comment: Your second answer doesn't work too, and you can't escape spaces like this "\ " in java.