# DownloadManager behaves strangly when destination file path contains space

Tags: android, pdf

My app downloads a pdf file using DownloadManager and saves it to a folder in the external storage.

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Class 10");
    File chapterFile = new File(folder, "jess301.pdf");
    request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://www.ncert.nic.in/NCERTS/l/jess301.pdf"))
                    .setTitle("Book Name")
                    .setDescription("Chapter Name")
                    .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(chapterFile))
                    .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
            downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

On many devices (e.g. nexus 4), the download manager saves the downloaded file to `Class 10/jess301.pdf` as expected.

But on some devices (e.g. Micromax A110 : version 4.0.4) the downloaded file is saved to a different loaction - `Class%2010/jess301.pdf`. On these devices, the space character in file path is replaced by `%20`.

When I run the code in an emulator with API 15, it works properly.

All the devices reporting this issue are running Android versions from 3.2 to 4.1. But the code works correctly on the corresponding emulators.

How can I make this work properly on all the devices?

My current workaround is to move the file from the wrong location to the right location.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301674/save-file-in-android-with-spaces-in-file-name) discusses same problem associated with StreamResult.

Comment: Can't you remove the space from the target folder?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It must contain the spaces in the file path. In fact the actual folder hierarchy is deeper that what I have shown here and contains three or more spaces.

Comment: Try unicode, e.g., `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Class\u002010");`